# Python 2.7 TCP server with a dynamic IP deployed in Docker

Tags: python-2.7, docker, azure-container-instances

I have a TCP server that listens to clients requests. It works without any issues when running it and executing the requests on a local environment.

The server is deployed in Azure Container Instances using Docker. I have been troubleshooting and the `socket.accept()` is returning a None object when running in a Docker image (both in local and Azure).

```
def __init__(self, ip_address, port):
    self.ipAddress = ip_address
    self.port = port
    self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.server_socket.bind((self.ipAddress, self.port))
    self.server_socket.listen(1)
    self.secure_socket = None
    self.worker = None

def connect(self):
    print("client connection before accept" )
    (client_connection, client_address) = self.server_socket.accept()
```

Running locally the server with an IP of 0.0.0.0 define at the server, allows the client to connect to the server 0.0.0.0:port. However, when I run this in docket the `accept()` method is not returning a socket and I think the issue is related with the IP address.

If the client is hosted in localhost, but the docker is running on local Docker, I see that the client 'hits' the server raising an exception, but never creates a valid socket.

The biggest issue that I face is deploying this in Azure Container Instances, since this service will give me a dynamic IP and I don't wish to create a static IP for this project.

Comment: So what is the issue you need to solve? Please provide more messages.